# FuzzyWuzzy partial_ratio string match

Tags: python, string, string-comparison, fuzzywuzzy

I have a sub-string that needs to checked against main-string , I had used FuzzyMatch Partial Ratio algorithm, but somehow, the score seems to be inappropriate

sub string :

`Aspire 1 14`

Main String:
`Acer Aspire 1 14 Inch Celeron 4GB 64GB Cloudbook - Red This sleek HD Acer Aspire 1 delivers an inviting tactile finish, featuring 4GB of RAM and an Intel Celeron Processor complete daily tasks and surf the internet seamlessly. Whilst 64GB of storage gives you enough space to easily store and share your important media and documents. #||#The classy look of the Aspire 1 is matched only by the convenience of its thin, easily portable design. #||#The Precision Touch-pad is more responsive than traditional touch-pads helping you work more effectively. #||#Model number: A114-32. #||#General features:#||#Size H1.79, W34.3, D24.5cm. #||#Weight 1.65kg. #||#Up to 10 hours battery life. #||#CPU, Memory and Operating System:#||#Intel Celeron N4000 processor. #||#Dual core processor. #||#1.1GHz processor speed with a burst speed of 2.6GHz. #||#4GB RAM DDR4. #||#64GB eMMC storage. #||#Microsoft Windows 10 S. #||#Display features:#||#14 inch screen. #||#High definition display. #||#Resolution 1366 x 768 pixels. #||#DVD optical drives:#||#Disc drive not included. #||#Graphics:#||#Intel UHD Graphics 600 graphics card. #||#Shared graphics card. #||#Interfaces and connectivity:#||#SD media card reader. #||#Secure Digital (SD), . #||#2 USB 2.0 ports. #||#1 USB 3.0 port. #||#1 Ethernet port. #||#1 HDMI port. #||#Bluetooth. #||#Wi-Fi enabled. #||#Multimedia features:#||#HD webcam. #||#Built-in mic. #||#Built-in audio sound system. #||#30 days Norton Security. #||#General information:#||#Manufacturer's 1 year guarantee. #||#EAN: 4710180446104.       Size H1.79, W34.3, D24.5cm.#||#Weight 1.65kg.#||#Up to 10 hours battery life.#||#Intel Celeron N4000 processor.#||#Dual core processor.#||#1.1GHz processor speed with a burst speed of 2.6GHz.#||#4GB RAM DDR4.#||#64GB eMMC storage.#||#Microsoft Windows 10 S.#||#14 inch screen.#||#High definition display.#||#Resolution 1366 x 768 pixels.#||#Disc drive not included.#||#Intel UHD Graphics 600 graphics card.#||#Shared graphics card.#||#SD media card reader.#||#Secure Digital (SD), .#||#2 USB 2.0 ports.#||#1 USB 3.0 port.#||#1 Ethernet port.#||#1 HDMI port.#||#Bluetooth.#||#Wi-Fi enabled.#||#HD webcam.#||#Built-in mic.#||#Built-in audio sound system.#||#30 days Norton Security.#||#Manufacturer's 1 year guarantee.#||#EAN: 4710180446104.`

Expected score is 100 but got only 55

Any suggestions are welcomed! Thanks in advance!

## Heading

Comment: Could you share the code your using to compare them? For me using fuzzywuzzy with `fuzz.partial_ratio(a, b)` returns a score of 100 as you expected.

Comment: I too used fuzz.partial_ratio(a,b) and figured out whenever either of strings length crosses threshold value(I remember it was around 1850) , SequenceMatcher has been set to false.

Though I resolved it by modifying internal logic, shortly I will send Pull request to FuzzyWuzzy Github code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out that if either of strings length (# of characters) crosses threshold value, partial_ratio sets Sequence Matcher to be false and the scores are not 100% even if there is a partial string match